# double form in shacn with error in inputs

Tags: reactjs, forms, components, shadcnui

For some reason, when I enter the salary input I receive "The specified value "<email>" cannot be parsed, or is out of range." and when I select the date in dataAdmissao I receive "The specified value "feminino" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd"."

For some reason, one form is interfering with the other

formulario.tsx

```
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import { formSchema1, formSchema2 } from '../../../Schemas/schemas.tsx';
import {
    Form,
    FormControl,
    FormField,
    FormItem,
    FormLabel,
    FormMessage,
} from '@/components/ui/form';
import { Input } from '@/components/ui/input';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { z } from 'zod';
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod';
import {
    Select,
    SelectContent,
    SelectItem,
    SelectTrigger,
    SelectValue,
} from '@/components/ui/select';
import Paginacao from './Paginacao';
import { IoSendOutline } from 'react-icons/io5';
import { Avatar, AvatarFallback, AvatarImage } from '@/components/ui/avatar';
import React, { ChangeEvent, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { RxAvatar } from 'react-icons/rx';

import {
    Popover,
    PopoverContent,
    PopoverTrigger,
} from '@/components/ui/popover';
import { Check, ChevronsUpDown } from 'lucide-react';
import {
    Command,
    CommandEmpty,
    CommandGroup,
    CommandInput,
    CommandItem,
    CommandList,
} from '@/components/ui/command';
import { cn } from '@/lib/utils';
import { FuncionarioType } from '@/hooks/getFuncionariosHooks.tsx';

const sexoOpcoes = [
    {
        id: 'masculino',
        opcao: 'Masculino',
    },
    {
        id: 'feminino',
        opcao: 'Feminino',
    },
];

const estadosBrasileiros = [
    { label: 'Acre', value: 'AC' },
    { label: 'Alagoas', value: 'AL' },
    { label: 'Amapá', value: 'AP' },
    { label: 'Amazonas', value: 'AM' },
    { label: 'Bahia', value: 'BA' },
    { label: 'Ceará', value: 'CE' },
    { label: 'Distrito Federal', value: 'DF' },
    { label: 'Espírito Santo', value: 'ES' },
    { label: 'Goiás', value: 'GO' },
    { label: 'Maranhão', value: 'MA' },
    { label: 'Mato Grosso', value: 'MT' },
    { label: 'Mato Grosso do Sul', value: 'MS' },
    { label: 'Minas Gerais', value: 'MG' },
    { label: 'Pará', value: 'PA' },
    { label: 'Paraíba', value: 'PB' },
    { label: 'Paraná', value: 'PR' },
    { label: 'Pernambuco', value: 'PE' },
    { label: 'Piauí', value: 'PI' },
    { label: 'Rio de Janeiro', value: 'RJ' },
    { label: 'Rio Grande do Norte', value: 'RN' },
    { label: 'Rio Grande do Sul', value: 'RS' },
    { label: 'Rondônia', value: 'RO' },
    { label: 'Roraima', value: 'RR' },
    { label: 'Santa Catarina', value: 'SC' },
    { label: 'São Paulo', value: 'SP' },
    { label: 'Sergipe', value: 'SE' },
    { label: 'Tocantins', value: 'TO' },
] as const;

const cargoOpcoes = [
    {
        id: 'desenvolvedor',
        opcao: 'Desenvolvedor',
    },
    {
        id: 'analista',
        opcao: 'Analista de RH',
    },
    {
        id: 'contador',
        opcao: 'Contador',
    },
    {
        id: 'vendedor',
        opcao: 'Vendedor',
    },
];
const setorOpcoes = [
    {
        id: 'tecnologia',
        opcao: 'Tecnologia da Informação',
    },
    {
        id: 'rh',
        opcao: 'Recursos Humanos',
    },
    {
        id: 'financeiro',
        opcao: 'Financeiro',
    },
    {
        id: 'vendas',
        opcao: 'Vendas',
    },
];

interface Cadastro1Type {
    nome: string;
    email: string;
    sexo: string;
    endereco: string[];
    telefone: string;
    fotoPerfil?: any;
    nascimento: string;
}
function getImageData(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
    Array.from(event.target.files!).forEach((image) =>
        dataTransfer.items.add(image)
    );

    const files = dataTransfer.files;
    const displayUrl = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files![0]);

    return { files, displayUrl };
}

export default function Formulario() {
    const [preview, setPreview] = useState('');
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
    const [funcionarioF1, setFuncionarioF1] = useState<Cadastro1Type | null>(
        null
    );
    const [funcionario, setFuncionario] = useState<FuncionarioType | null>(null);

    const form2 = useForm({
        resolver: zodResolver(formSchema2),
        defaultValues: {
            setor: '',
            cargo: '',
            dataAdmissao: '',
            salario: '',
        },
    });

    const form1 = useForm({
        resolver: zodResolver(formSchema1),
        defaultValues: {
            nome: '',
            email: '',
            sexo: '',
            rua: '',
            numero: '',
            cep: '',
            cidade: '',
            estado: '',
            telefone: '',
            fotoPerfil: undefined,
            nascimento: '',
        },
    });
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(funcionario);
    }, [funcionario]);

    let onSubmit1 = async (data: z.infer<typeof formSchema1>) => {
        const endereco = [
            data.rua,
            data.numero,
            data.cep,
            data.cidade,
            data.estado,
        ];
        setFuncionarioF1({
            nome: data.nome,
            email: data.email,
            sexo: data.sexo,
            endereco: endereco,
            telefone: data.telefone,
            fotoPerfil: data.fotoPerfil,
            nascimento: data.nascimento,
        });
    };
    if (funcionarioF1) {
        let form1 = 0;
        const onSubmit2 = async (data: z.infer<typeof formSchema2>) => {
            console.log(data);
        };
        return (
            <div className="flex w-full flex-col items-center justify-center">
                <Form {...form2}>
                    <form
                        onSubmit={form2.handleSubmit(onSubmit2)}
                        className="w-[70%] space-y-8 rounded-3xl border-[4px] border-mainColor p-5"
                    >
                        <div className="flex flex-col items-center rounded-t-3xl   p-3 pb-3 text-[30px] font-bold text-mainColor ">
                            Cadastro de Funcionario
                        </div>
                        <div className="text-2xl font-bold">Informações do Funcionário</div>

                        <div className="flex">
                            <div className="flex w-[50%] flex-col">
                                <FormField
                                    control={form2.control}
                                    name="setor"
                                    render={({ field }) => (
                                        <FormItem>
                                            <FormLabel>Setor</FormLabel>
                                            <Select
                                                onValueChange={field.onChange}
                                                defaultValue={field.value}
                                            >
                                                <FormControl>
                                                    <SelectTrigger className="w-[180px] border-[2px] border-mainColor ">
                                                        <SelectValue placeholder="Selecionar" />
                                                    </SelectTrigger>
                                                </FormControl>
                                                <SelectContent
                                                    className="bg-branco text-preto "
                                                    {...field}
                                                >
                                                    {setorOpcoes.map((opcao) => (
                                                        <SelectItem key={opcao.id} value={opcao.id}>
                                                            {opcao.opcao}
                                                        </SelectItem>
                                                    ))}
                                                </SelectContent>
                                            </Select>
                                            <FormMessage />
                                        </FormItem>
                                    )}
                                />

                                <FormField
                                    control={form2.control}
                                    name="salario"
                                    render={({ field }) => (
                                        <FormItem className="w-[80%]">
                                            <FormLabel>Salario</FormLabel>
                                            <FormControl>
                                                <Input
                                                    type="text"
                                                    className="border-[2px] border-mainColor text-preto"
                                                    placeholder="Salario"
                                                    {...field}
                                                />
                                            </FormControl>
                                            <FormMessage />
                                        </FormItem>
                                    )}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex w-[50%] flex-col">
                                <FormField
                                    control={form2.control}
                                    name="cargo"
                                    render={({ field }) => (
                                        <FormItem>
                                            <FormLabel>Cargo</FormLabel>
                                            <Select
                                                onValueChange={field.onChange}
                                                defaultValue={field.value}
                                            >
                                                <FormControl>
                                                    <SelectTrigger className="w-[180px] border-[2px] border-mainColor ">
                                                        <SelectValue placeholder="Selecionar" />
                                                    </SelectTrigger>
                                                </FormControl>
                                                <SelectContent
                                                    className="bg-branco text-preto "
                                                    {...field}
                                                >
                                                    {cargoOpcoes.map((opcao) => (
                                                        <SelectItem key={opcao.id} value={opcao.id}>
                                                            {opcao.opcao}
                                                        </SelectItem>
                                                    ))}
                                                </SelectContent>
                                            </Select>
                                            <FormMessage />
                                        </FormItem>
                                    )}
                                />

                                <FormField
                                    control={form2.control}
                                    name="dataAdmissao"
                                    render={({ field }) => (
                                        <FormItem>
                                            <FormLabel>Data de Admissao</FormLabel>
                                            <FormControl>
                                                <Input
                                                    {...field}
                                                    type="date"
                                                    className="w-[80%] border-[2px] border-mainColor text-preto"
                                                    placeholder="Selecione a data"
                                                />
                                            </FormControl>
                                            <FormMessage></FormMessage>
                                        </FormItem>
                                    )}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <Button variant="outline" className="gap-1 px-5 py-4" type="submit">
                            Continuar
                            <IoSendOutline />
                        </Button>
                        <Paginacao />
                    </form>
                </Form>
            </div>
        );
    }
    return (
        <div className="flex w-full flex-col items-center justify-center">
            <Form {...form1}>
                <form
                    onSubmit={form1.handleSubmit(onSubmit1)}
                    className="w-[70%] space-y-8 rounded-3xl border-[4px] border-mainColor p-5"
                >
                    <div className="flex flex-col items-center rounded-t-3xl   p-3 pb-3 text-[30px] font-bold text-mainColor ">
                        Cadastro de Funcionario
                    </div>
                    <div className="text-2xl font-bold">Informações de Contato </div>
                    <div className="flex">
                        <div className="flex w-[50%] flex-col">
                            <FormField
                                control={form1.control}
                                name="nome"
                                render={({ field }) => (
                                    <FormItem>
                                        <FormLabel>Nome</FormLabel>
                                        <FormControl>
                                            <Input
                                                {...field}
                                                type="name"
                                                placeholder="Digite o nome"
                                                className="w-[90%] border-[2px] border-mainColor"
                                            ></Input>
                                        </FormControl>
                                        <FormMessage />
                                    </FormItem>
                                )}
                            />
                            <FormField
                                control={form1.control}
                                name="email"
                                render={({ field }) => (
                                    <FormItem>
                                        <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
                                        <FormControl>
                                            <Input
                                                {...field}
                                                className="w-[90%] border-[2px] border-mainColor text-preto"
                                                placeholder="Digite o Email"
                                            />
                                        </FormControl>
                                        <FormMessage />
                                    </FormItem>
                                )}
                            />
                            <div className="flex w-full ">
                                <FormField
                                    control={form1.control}
                                    name="rua"
                                    render={({ field }) => (
                                        <FormItem className="mr-5 w-[72%] flex-initial">
                                            <FormLabel>Rua</FormLabel>
                                            <FormControl>
                                                <Input
                                                    {...field}
                                                    className="border-[2px] border-mainColor text-preto"
                                                    placeholder="Digite a rua"
                                                />
                                            </FormControl>
                                            <FormMessage />
                                        </FormItem>
                                    )}
                                />

                                <FormField
                                    control={form1.control}
                                    name="numero"
                                    render={({ field }) => (
                                        <FormItem className="w-[15%]">
                                            <FormLabel>Numero</FormLabel>
                                            <FormControl>
                                                <Input
                                                    {...field}
                                                    className=" border-[2px] border-mainColor text-preto"
                                                    placeholder="Numero"
                                                />
                                            </FormControl>
                                            <FormMessage />
                                        </FormItem>
                                    )}
                                />
                                <div className="w-[10%]"></div>
                            </div>
                            <FormField
                                control={form1.control}
                                name="cep"
                                render={({ field }) => (
                                    <FormItem>
                                        <FormLabel>CEP</FormLabel>
                                        <FormControl>
                                            <Input
                                                {...field}
                                                className="w-[90%] border-[2px] border-mainColor text-preto"
                                                placeholder="Digite o CEP"
                                            />
                                        </FormControl>
                                        <FormMessage />
                                    </FormItem>
                                )}
                            />
                            <div className=" w-[90%] justify-between align-bottom">
                                <FormField
                                    control={form1.control}
                                    name="cidade"
                                    render={({ field }) => (
                                        <FormItem>
                                            <FormLabel>Cidade</FormLabel>
                                            <FormControl>
                                                <Input
                                                    {...field}
                                                    className="w-[100%] border-[2px] border-mainColor text-preto"
                                                    placeholder="Digite a cidade"
                                                />
                                            </FormControl>
                                            <FormMessage />
                                        </FormItem>
                                    )}
                                />
                                <FormField
                                    control={form1.control}
                                    name="estado"
                                    render={({ field }) => (
                                        <FormItem className="flex flex-col pt-2 ">
                                            <FormLabel>Estado</FormLabel>
                                            <Popover open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
                                                <PopoverTrigger
                                                    asChild
                                                    className="border-[2px] border-mainColor"
                                                >
                                                    <FormControl>
                                                        <Button
                                                            variant="outline"
                                                            role="combobox"
                                                            aria-expanded={open}
                                                            className={cn('w-[200px] justify-between')}
                                                        >
                                                            {value
                                                                ? estadosBrasileiros.find(
                                                                        (estado) => estado.value === value
                                                                    )?.label
                                                                : 'Selecione o estado'}
                                                            <ChevronsUpDown className="ml-2 h-4 w-4 shrink-0 opacity-50" />
                                                        </Button>
                                                    </FormControl>
                                                </PopoverTrigger>
                                                <PopoverContent className="w-[200px] bg-branco p-0 text-preto">
                                                    <Command>
                                                        <CommandInput placeholder="Selecione o estado" />
                                                        <CommandEmpty>Estado nao encontrado</CommandEmpty>
                                                        <CommandList className="">
                                                            <CommandGroup className="bg-branco font-bold text-preto ">
                                                                {estadosBrasileiros.map((estado) => (
                                                                    <CommandItem
                                                                        className="font-bold text-preto "
                                                                        value={estado.value}
                                                                        key={estado.value}
                                                                        onSelect={(currentValue) => {
                                                                            setValue(currentValue);
                                                                            form1.setValue('estado', estado.value);
                                                                            setOpen(false);
                                                                        }}
                                                                    >
                                                                        <Check
                                                                            className={cn(
                                                                                'mr-2 h-4 w-4',
                                                                                estado.value === field.value
                                                                                    ? 'opacity-100'
                                                                                    : 'opacity-0'
                                                                            )}
                                                                        />
                                                                        {estado.label}
                                                                    </CommandItem>
                                                                ))}
                                                            </CommandGroup>
                                                        </CommandList>
                                                    </Command>
                                                </PopoverContent>
                                            </Popover>
                                            <FormMessage />
                                        </FormItem>
                                    )}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex w-[50%] flex-col">
                            <div className="">
                                <FormField
                                    control={form1.control}
                                    name="fotoPerfil"
                                    render={({ field: { onChange, value, ...field } }) => (
                                        <FormItem className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center ">
                                            <FormLabel htmlFor="picture">Foto de Perfil</FormLabel>{' '}
                                            <Avatar className="h-24 w-24 border-[4px] border-mainColor">
                                                <AvatarImage src={preview} />
                                                <AvatarFallback>
                                                    <RxAvatar className="h-24 w-24" />
                                                </AvatarFallback>
                                            </Avatar>
                                            <FormControl>
                                                <Input
                                                    type="file"
                                                    {...field}
                                                    onChange={(event) => {
                                                        const { files, displayUrl } = getImageData(event);
                                                        setPreview(displayUrl);
                                                        onChange(files);
                                                    }}
                                                    className="w-[70%] rounded-full border-[2px] border-mainColor"
                                                />
                                            </FormControl>
                                            <FormMessage />
                                        </FormItem>
                                    )}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <FormField
                                control={form1.control}
                                name="sexo"
                                render={({ field }) => (
                                    <FormItem>
                                        <FormLabel>Sexo</FormLabel>
                                        <Select
                                            onValueChange={field.onChange}
                                            defaultValue={field.value}
                                        >
                                            <FormControl>
                                                <SelectTrigger className="w-[180px] border-[2px] border-mainColor ">
                                                    <SelectValue placeholder="Selecionar" />
                                                </SelectTrigger>
                                            </FormControl>
                                            <SelectContent
                                                className="bg-branco text-preto "
                                                {...field}
                                            >
                                                {sexoOpcoes.map((opcao) => (
                                                    <SelectItem key={opcao.id} value={opcao.id}>
                                                        {opcao.opcao}
                                                    </SelectItem>
                                                ))}
                                            </SelectContent>
                                        </Select>
                                        <FormMessage />
                                    </FormItem>
                                )}
                            />
                            <FormField
                                control={form1.control}
                                name="telefone"
                                render={({ field }) => (
                                    <FormItem>
                                        <FormLabel>Numero de celular</FormLabel>
                                        <FormControl>
                                            <Input
                                                {...field}
                                                className="w-[90%] border-[2px] border-mainColor text-preto"
                                                placeholder="Digite o numero"
                                            />
                                        </FormControl>
                                        <FormMessage />
                                    </FormItem>
                                )}
                            />
                            <FormField
                                control={form1.control}
                                name="nascimento"
                                render={({ field }) => (
                                    <FormItem>
                                        <FormLabel>Data de Aniversário</FormLabel>
                                        <FormControl>
                                            <Input
                                                {...field}
                                                type="date"
                                                className="w-[90%] border-[2px] border-mainColor text-preto"
                                                placeholder="Selecione a data"
                                            />
                                        </FormControl>
                                        <FormMessage></FormMessage>
                                    </FormItem>
                                )}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <Button variant="outline" className="gap-1 px-5 py-4" type="submit">
                        Continuar
                        <IoSendOutline />
                    </Button>
                    <Paginacao />
                </form>
            </Form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

schema.tsx

```
import { z } from 'zod';

const MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 5;
const ACCEPTED_IMAGE_MIME_TYPES = [
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/jpg',
    'image/png',
    'image/webp',
];

export const formSchema1 = z.object({
    nome: z
        .string()
        .min(2, { message: 'O nome deve ter no mínimo 2 caracteres' })
        .max(50, { message: 'O nome deve ter no máximo 50 caracteres' }),
    email: z.string().email({ message: 'Email inválido' }),
    sexo: z.string(),
    rua: z.string().min(1, { message: 'Digite o nome da rua' }),
    numero: z.string().min(1, { message: 'Digite o número' }),
    cep: z.string().min(8, { message: 'CEP inválido' }),
    cidade: z.string().min(1, { message: 'Digite o nome da cidade' }),
    estado: z.string({ required_error: 'Selecione o estado' }),
    telefone: z.string().regex(/^\d{10,11}$/, { message: 'Telefone inválido' }),
    fotoPerfil: z
        .any()
        .refine((files) => {
            return files?.[0]?.size <= MAX_FILE_SIZE;
        }, `A imagem ultrapassou o tamanho maximo de 5MB.`)
        .refine(
            (files) => ACCEPTED_IMAGE_MIME_TYPES.includes(files?.[0]?.type),
            'Apenas jpg, jpeg, png e webp sao os formatos suportados.'
        ),
    nascimento: z.string().refine(
        (value) => {
            const date = new Date(value);
            return !isNaN(date.getTime());
        },
        { message: 'A data de aniversário deve estar em um formato válido' }
    ),
});

export const formSchema2 = z.object({
    setor: z.string(),
    cargo: z.string(),
    salario: z.string().min(3, { message: 'Digite o salario' }),
    dataAdmissao: z.string().refine(
        (value) => {
            const dataAdmissao = new Date(value);
            return !isNaN(dataAdmissao.getTime());
        },
        { message: 'A data de admissao deve estar em um formato válido' }
    ),
});
```